# Text messaging so slow it is nearly unusable

Tags: sms, performance

I have a Galaxy S5 running 4.4.2. I am trying to send a text message to a certain contact.

When I select their name from the list of messages, there is a 30 second delay. While typing, sometimes there will be a 10-15 second delay for each letter. If they send me a message while I'm trying to type, there will be a 30-60 second delay. Texting this person is so slow it is almost unusable. Other contacts are slow as well, but still usable.

This is with no other apps running.

My guess is that this could be caused by the lengthy text message history for this particular contact, but I doubt this is the case for the following reason: It seems extremely unlikely that I should be unable to store and display several megs of text on hardware made in 2014. I want to preserve this text history in any case, but I don't necessarily need to display it all on the screen at once.

Thanks!

Edit: I have tried clearing the cache, no effect.

Comment: do you have more than 500 or 1000 sms in your inbox..???

Comment: when you try to delete 1 sms from inbox does it takes more time then it should be..???

Comment: Yes, I have a lot of text messages. I want to save them. They are ascii data, it shouldn't be unfeasible to save and read ascii data in the year 2015, haha.

Comment: I have this problem also on 5.1 but was fine until I upgraded from 4.4. As a programmer, I can say that I suspect that they have an order n-squared algorithm in there somewhere. So 100 messages in a conversation takes 10000 times as long as 1 message. That is just my guess after 35 years as a developer. Some of these young folks forget the basics. ;-) Any order-n algorithm beats the most highly optimized order n-squared algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

*Most Likely your phone doesn't have enough Ram*

---

Are you using a custom keyboard or just the default keyboard? As custom keyboards can lag out your phone

**So your options can be:**

1. You could slow down your typing  on your android phone

   or
2. You can increase the CPU Frequency and/or Governor on your phone, thus it
   ticks over a bit quicker and/or allocating more CPU time to the keyboard and allowing you to type faster

***Note:** You shouldn't do anything unnecessary to your phone Like change your CPU settings un-less necessary and If you have the know the **How-To**

### Why Scale the CPU And/Or Change the Governor?

You tap a few keys, the CPU ramps up, does it’s magic, presents its suggestions, then spins down again. You tap another few keys, and the CPU ramps up again, does its thing again, then spins down again.

The faster you type and the more pauses you take between words, the more apparent the lag is, and the more frustrating it is to the user

So you can change the CPU Governor to a govern that allocates CPU time differently, and also the CPU frequency. Thus it can allow you to type with less lag because the keyboard is/can get my CPU allocation

Comment: Why did you not consider seeking clarification first?

Comment: @Firelord  I didn't think to seek clarification at the time as it slipped my mind.

-Should I take this answer down Until they answer my Comment??  If this answer isn't good enough I can delete it.

Comment: I don't think RAM is the issue.

Comment: I'm using the standard keyboard. After a bit the lags seems to "settle", but I'll get another huge lag spike as more texts arrive, or if I try to change contacts, or if I send my message.

Comment: @catpants All that i can really say is that you'll just have to be patient while typing. Changing the CPU Governor to something that allocates more fairly/powerful is my only suggestion left, Other then backing up the messages and then restoring the messages onto the phone after a factory reset. You can't really do to much.